# read_csv doesn't read the column names correctly on this file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file as follows:

```
0 5
1 10
2 15
3 20
4 25
```

I want to save it as a dataframe with x,y axes as names, then plot it. However when I assign `x`,`y` I get a messed up DataFrame, what is happening?

```
column_names = ['x','y']
x = pd.read_csv('csv-file.csv', header = None, names = column_names)
print(x)

          x   y
0   0 5 NaN
1  1 10 NaN
2  2 15 NaN
3  3 20 NaN
4  4 25 NaN
```

I've tried without specifying `None` for `header`, to no avail.

Comment: Because strictly, that's not a comma-separated value (CSV), it's whitespace-separated value, sometimes generically referred to as TSV (tab-separated value).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add parameter `sep="\s+"` or `delim_whitespace=True` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""0 5
1 10
2 15
3 20
4 25"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
column_names = ['x','y']
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", header = None, names = column_names)

print (df)
   x   y
0  0   5
1  1  10
2  2  15
3  3  20
4  4  25
```

Or:

```
column_names = ['x','y']
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp),
                 delim_whitespace=True, 
                 header = None, 
                 names = column_names)

print (df)
   x   y
0  0   5
1  1  10
2  2  15
3  3  20
4  4  25
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try this :

```
import pandas as pd    

column_names = ['x','y']
df = pd.read_csv('csv-file.csv',header=None)
df.columns = column_names
```